# Let's say I have a long HTML file that includes the string "USER_NAME='FOO BAR'". How do I just extract FOO BAR using BASH?

Tags: string, bash, awk, grep, extract

I have a long html file and I want to extract a value associated with a variable name. I assume this will require using grep, awk, or sed.

An example from the file: "USER_NAME='Foo Bar X. 1003. User since 2003.'" Single quotes are the only delimiters.

Comment: I guess I should have made it clearer that the USER_NAME entries could be of any length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try (quick & dirty)

```
grep -oP 'USER_NAME=\K\S+' your.html
grep -oP "USER_NAME='\K[^']+" your.html
grep -oP 'USER_NAME="\K[^"]+' your.html
```

### update

since you didn't give any example data, try above 3 lines, hope one of them works for you.

Comment: This doesn't work, because the user name is more than one word.

Comment: @MatthewKlinestiver then give a better example. is there quotes? or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each config is on a newline, and = cannot also be in the username...

```
grep ^USER_NAME your.html | awk -F "=" '{print $2}'
```

2 steps:

1) retrieve lines that begin with USER_NAME in your file

2) separate the line on a "=" delimiter and print the 2nd value

Comment: Unfortunately, the configs aren't on new lines. Also, they can be more than 2 words long.

Comment: How is your file delimited? Can you post a sample?